# How to fill list at design time without inherited properties?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a control like this:

```
Class TextBoxEx
    Inherits TextBox
    Public Property MyCustomProperty As String
End Class
```

And a component like this:

```
Class Config
    Inherits Component
    Private _Controls As List(Of TextBoxEx)
    Public Property Controls As List(Of TextBoxEx)
        Get
            Return _Controls
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of TextBoxEx))
            _Controls = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

So after dropping this component on a form, i want to fill this list in designer, i also wanted to see only the property MyCustomProperty of the TextBoxEx control and not all the properties of the TextBox.

C# code:

```
class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}

class Config : Component
{
    private List<TextBoxEx> _Controls;
    public List<TextBoxEx> Controls
    {
        get
        {
            return _Controls;
        }
        set
        {
            _Controls = value;
        }
    }
}
```

someone help me please

Comment: Use the `Browsable(false)` attribute on all the inherited properties which you would have to override in your custom class.

Comment: Great, thanks! But what about filling the list with the TextBoxEX that are in Design?

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing there.  Why is it a component?  Etc.

Comment: You should really be asking two separate questions for this.  To achieve the _hiding_ of inherited properties while using the designer, there are various designer and TypeDescriptor solutions that could be implemented.   Overriding properties as @LarsTech has suggested will work, but is not ideal.

Comment: A relatively simple soultion would be to implement the [ICustomTypeDescriptor Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) on your `TextBoxEx` class and code the two `GetProperties` overloads to only return the `MyCustomProperty` descriptor.  All other interface methods would return the corresponding method result from the [TypeDescriptor Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx).